# How to decrease storage size for PostgreSQL on Google Cloud?

Tags: database, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

I moved some of my data from PostgreSQL to BigQuery.

Before PostgreSQL database was using 130 GB of storage, now I only need 30GB.

However, in the Google Cloud Console GUI, I still see that PostgreSQL still allocating 130 GB of storage, while 100GB of it is empty (see the attached screenshot).

Does it mean that Google Cloud is still charging me for 130GB of storage?
What can I do to get rid of that unused storage space?

[image: Screenshot from Google Cloud]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is currently impossible to [reduce the storage](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/instance-settings#storage-capacity-2ndgen) capacity of a Cloud SQL instance. The storage allocation is permanent and cannot reduce only increased. However, there is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63069754) for reducing the capacity of a Cloud SQL instance that is worth following for future updates.

To use a smaller storage capacity, export data as an [SQL dump file](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/exporting#cloud-sql) and then, configure a new Cloud SQL instance with the desired capacity. Then [import the SQL dump file](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/importing#importing_data_from_a_sql_dump_file_in) to store all your data in the new instance. To achieve efficient and less expensive imports/exports follow these [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export#best_practices_for_importing_and_exporting) from the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

It's impossible to **decreace Storage size(capacity)** for all [**PostgreSQL**](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/instance-settings#storage-capacity-2ndgen), [**MySQL**](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-settings#storage-capacity-2ndgen) and [**SQL Server**](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/instance-settings#storage-capacity-2ndgen) on **Cloud SQL**. **Only increasing Storage size** is possible and **Yes**, **GCP** is still charging you for **130GB storage cost**.

If you really want to **decreace  Storage size** from **130 GB** to **30GB** on **Cloud SQL**, you can **export the data from the existing instance** :

[image]

Then, **import the data into the new instance created with the Storage size 30 GB**. This way, you can **decreace  Storage size** from **130 GB** to **30GB** on **Cloud SQL**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Google is charging you for the "unused" storage as well.

Good news is that there's a new [Database Migration Service](https://cloud.google.com/database-migration/docs/postgres/create-migration-job) available now.

It is less manual than the export/import process suggested above. Select **continuous replication** to minimize the outage. It'll first do a full-dump (similar to export/import) copy and then continue with logical replication (syncing all the diffs in real time) with the use of **pglogical** extension to Postgres.

Just make sure you enable the extension on **every database** managed by your DB engine first (run `CREATE EXTENSION pglogical;`), otherwise the migration may fail.

You can monitor the status of the migration and decide to **promote** the replicated DB once ready, which will complete the migration process and you can redirect your App to the new DB. Total outage less than 5 mins.